# Dynamically creating controls asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a website where you can take a multi-choice quiz. There can be 1 to 5 possible answers for each question in the quiz. I am having trouble figuring out how to dynamically making the controls for the quiz based on how many answers there are. I can get the number of answers easily. 
so if there are 3 answers i need to generate 3 textboxes (readonly) and corresponding radiobutton list. Then when the user presses a button the data is submitted and the next question is loaded. I am trying to do this all in C#.

Comment: How do you do it statically?  Posting that code can give us a better idea of what frameworks you are using.

Comment: With only a maximum of 5 I would be tempted to have 5 mostly static options. Dynamically populate the text and hide unused questions.

Comment: If I do it statically I can use the design view in visual studios to place them with CSS. I have tried making them statically and toggling the visibility but it seems a bit bulky.  Something like if(1){Show only 1 button and textbox} (if2){show only 2 buttons and textbox} ect.

Answer (score 2):

I once did exactly same but creating only textbox dynamically.I am copying my code(bit busy to make changes right now) ,please edit to your need:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  

<head runat="server">  
    <title></title>  

    </script>  

</head>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">  
    function GetDynamicTextBox(value)  
    {  
        return '<input name = "DynamicTextBox"  class="dynamic"  type="text" value = "' + "mymonthname" + '" />' +  
            '<input name = "DynamicTextBox1"  class="dynamic"  type="text" value = "' + "myYearname" + '" />' +  
            '<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this)" />'  
    }  

    function AddTextBox()  
    {  
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');  
        div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");  
        document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);  
    }  

    function RemoveTextBox(div)  
    {  
        document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);  
    }  
    //    function RecreateDynamicTextboxes() {    
    //        var values = "vishal";    
    //        if (values != null) {    
    //            var html = "";    
    //            for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {    
    //                html += "<div>" + GetDynamicTextBox(values[i]) + "</div>";    
    //            }    
    //            document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").innerHTML = html;    
    //        }    
    //    }  
</script>  

</head>  

<body>  
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  

        <div id="TextBoxContainer" style="text-align: center;" class="step">  
        </div>  

        <div>  
            <div style="text-align: center;" id="setPrinteraxcis1">  
                <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox()" class="ANPClass" />  
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </form>  
</body>
```

and to access the values,you need to write below code in .cs"

```
 string[] textboxValues = Request.Form.GetValues("DynamicTextBox");
                        if (textboxValues == null || textboxValues.Length == 0)
                        {
                            string empty = "true";
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                            this.Values = serializer.Serialize(textboxValues);

                            foreach (string textboxValue in textboxValues)
                            {

                                MultipleId.Add(textboxValue);
                            }
                        }
```

where MultipleId is an arraylist:

```
  public ArrayList MultipleId = new ArrayList();
```

**P.S.**
I read your requirement that you need on basis of some critteria,then you can use an counter in AddTextbox method and loop to create desired number of textbox.